# 安らぎの人 translation into English

Tags: translation

I'm watching an old anime, and the main character at one point says:

> 彼は私の安らぎの人です。

The subtitles said, "He's the one that I love." But I'm unfamiliar with the use of 安らぎ in this context, and am wondering if there's a more appropriate/accurate way of understanding this? My understanding is that 安らぎ means 'tranquil/peaceful', so I would literally translate the phrase as "He is the person with whom I feel most peaceful." However, the main character does love this boy she is referring to, so I'm guessing this may be a commonly understood way of referring to someone you love? I feel I might be missing something culturally about this phrase, which is giving me a hard time when trying to understand it.

Comment: As broccoli forest wrote, I think that you interpreted the sentence correctly. But in subtitles, an accurate translation is often too long or unnatural in the context, and has to be replaced with a less accurate translation which at least fits the context well. So you should not assume that subtitles (even high-quality ones) are accurate translations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a fixed phrase, or something related to or implies love (as far as I know), but I think your translation is correct, considering 安らぎの placed before something is all but always used for "provides peace of mind" in actual usages (from random Google hits):

- 「[海を見ながら安らぎの音楽を](https://youtu.be/4XqwKFl97ag)」 "Listen to relaxing music with sight of the sea"
- 「[家庭より職場が安らぎの場？](https://www.circl.jp/2015/09/25/4537/)」 "The workplace is where you feel at ease rather than your home?"
- 「[安らぎの祈りで問題に向き合う](http://www.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/nba/20090527/155826/)」 "Face your problems with 'serenity prayer'"

and it doesn't go against my intuition.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate 安らぎの人 as 'a person I'm comfortable with' or literally 'a person who gives me peace of mind.'